# Simple excel adding two cells and displaying alphabetically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This seems like an incredibly simple problem but I can not figure out how to solve it.
I am trying create a new column with pair of place names in from an excel sheet, a simplified version of which is shown below.

**Sheet 1:**

```
   |  A             
1    Dunfermline           
2    Torryburn           
3    Burntisland            
4    Kinghorn           
5    Torryburn           
6    Carnock
```

I would like to pull out into B1, B3, B5 et. the pairs of places. I have managed to do this using

=A2 & "-" & A3

but I would like the place name that begins with the letter earliest in the alphabet to be displayed first, as below. My method does not work in the case of B5 - I can only return 'Torryburn - Carnock'

**Desired Output:**

```
   |  A             | B
1    Dunfermline      Dunfermline - Torryburn     
2    Torryburn           
3    Burntisland      Burntisland - Kinghorn      
4    Kinghorn           
5    Torryburn        Carnock - Torryburn   
6    Carnock
```

Is there a method of sorting the cells and adding them together as required?

Comment: This question should not be here - nothing related to programming.

Comment: @Juliusz I am starting today to look in the Excel tag but I guess that this question fits pretty well here; that is, Excel-related issues, like formulae. If you want programming (= macros), you should include the tag VBA or VBA-Excel, but the OP didn't do that so I understand that everything is OK.

Comment: @varocarbas But that's the typical super user question - simple formulae in Excel, which are advanced for an Excel user, but really nothing interesting for programmers. It is a tough call, but you can easily be swarmed by this kind of questions here.

Comment: @Juliusz OK. I don't have any strong opinion; as said, today is the first day when I am looking at this tag, I saw this unanswered question and just wrote my answer (too slow and not too well, because LittleBobbyTables was quicker and better :)... didn't realise while writing mine). I don't think that I will be answering this kind of questions too often, but perhaps others do (the ones following the Excel tag). This is undoubtedly an excel-formula question; you cannot avoid simple questions to come in (there are really simple, strictly-programming-related questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the [`IF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) function (or [`IIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557186.aspx), depending on your version of Excel) to check if A2 < A3, and then show the appropriate reuslts.  For example:

```
=IF(A2 < A3, A2 & "-" & A3, A3 & "-" & A2)
```

Answer (score 3):

<> does the trick:

```
=IF(A2<A3,A2,A3) & "-" & IF(A2>A3,A2,A3)
```

Comment: If you want to leave every other cell empty "": `=IF(MOD(ROW(A2),2)=0,IF(A2<A3,A2,A3) & "-" & IF(A2>A3,A2,A3),"")`

Comment: (to the coward multi-downvoter) I hope that you read that: I will let know SO about this curious two in a row down-voting, just to track your PATHETIC activity.